# Explore files using Android Studio

Tags: file-system, file-transfer, file-management

Is it possible browsing the device filesystem with the current version of AS? I've read that in the menu *View > Tool Windows > Device File Explorer* there should be the suitable tool, but I cannot see anything.

Comment: I've just checked Android Studio 3.5 for Windows, and it's there on *View - Tool Windows - Device File Explorer*. By "cannot see anything", did you mean there's no menu entry, or it didn't show Device File Explorer on one of the Sidebars, or it didn't show your device, or it didn't show your device content? Also on Android's official documentation: [View on-device files with Device File Explorer](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/device-file-explorer)

Comment: @AndrewT. I follow the menu till to the entry *Tool Windows* in the upper menu *View*, and here I don't see anything (i.e. *Device file explorer* is missed). Android Studio for Linux

Comment: The menu is also present here (AS 3.5 on Windows). I find it quite interesting that this explorer is capable of listing `/data/data/` which is not possible via adb on an unrooted device.

Comment: @Robert Is `/data/data/` available *only* for apps in debugging mode on the device, not for all the installed apps? Maybe if I haven't installed any such app the *Device Explorer* doesn't appear. Do you see it in the menu even *without* any app in debugging mode?